# Cannot enable HTTPS on Symfony 5 local web server

Tags: symfony, command-line-interface

I'm on Windows 10 and I run this command as root user `symfony server:ca:install` but it's don't work instead I have this following message :

> You might have to enter your root password to install the local Certificate Authority certificate
>   failed to install the local Certificate Authority: add cert: failed adding cert: Access denied.

I'm already a admin user, any idea ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to run CMS in admin mode.

- Click start icon or press windows button.
- write `cmd`
- right click on Command Line and open as admin (or something like that)
- navigate to folder try to install CA with a same command

Hope this is gonna help :)